# SP2010: how to link to document on my Title column on document library?

Tags: 2010, document-library, hyperlink, out-of-the-box

I am using sp2010. I have a document library with some columns. I see the column name with a link to the document. But I would like to implement this on the title column. Is it possible to implement a link to the document from the title column?

Answer (score 1):

or just edit view aspx in designer and add linkToItem="TRUE" for the desired column

example:

```
<ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
                <FieldRef Name="Title" linkToItem="TRUE"/>
                <FieldRef Name="field3"/>
                <FieldRef Name="field4"/>
                <FieldRef Name="field5"/>
</ViewFields>
```

Comment: in SP2013 ensure the [exact capitalisation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeapps/en-US/929deaf8-5372-4907-b965-b2f829da2b5e/linktoitem-not-working-for-any-column?forum=sharepointcustomization#20a44b94-9f71-4146-b74d-7c6c23fe61e5) "linkToItem" otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

when uploading documents there is already an ootb column that is called Name that links to the document, either in the default view change the name as visible (ticked) and hide the title (untick). That will only show the name.

You can have both shown, to make the first column as clickable (linked) than within the view also set the Name column and 1 on the list.

[image]

Comment: I dont want to use the name column because it is not user friendly (example: summary_report-2014.pdf). I would like to make the title clickable because it is user friendly (example: Summary Report 2014).

Comment: that isnt an easy task but if you want than follow this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424763/Zen-and-the-art-of-XSLT-rendering-fields-SharePoin

Comment: only other method is to use jquery, you would need to have some logic so it knows what level the item is on, take from col one(Title) and replace the text on col 2(Name) but keeping the url inplace! this would be done on page load.... if i get time i could write it out but im a bit bussy atm

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you're asking out of the box. You could, however, use SharePoint Designer to create a DataView that has a column containing the Name hyperlink and the Title text value.  If you want the clickable link to be available in standard views, you could create a new hyperlink field using a workflow to set the value from Title and Path.

1. Create a hyperlink field
2. Create a workflow that runs on create and change (assuming users are allowed to change Title and that the hyperlink field will need to be updated at that time)
3. Set a variable to [%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%], [%CurrentItem:Title%]
4. Set your hyperlink field to your variable